# How to configure eslint on starting react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, eslint, eslintrc

I am working on react application with typescript. I have created react application using :
npx create-react-app test-app --template typescript

eslint is already configured here when we create app using create-react-app in react-scripts

But when I do npm start, eslint error not coming

In App.tsx, I added one console.log("test") for testing. And then in eslintConfig in package.json, added below :

rules : {
"non-console" :"error"
}

Now, when I start react application, not getting error message in console that console.log is used.
But, when I save App.tsx, error message comes for console.

How can I get eslint this console error on starting react application itself.

Answer (score -1):

Add `"lint:fix": "tslint --fix --project ."`, in scripts (package.json)

Create tslint.json

```
{
  "defaultSeverity": "error",
  "extends": [
    "tslint:latest",
    "tslint-react",
    "tslint-plugin-prettier",
    "tslint-config-prettier"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "no-angle-bracket-type-assertion": false,
    "no-object-literal-type-assertion": false,
    "prettier/prettier": [
      "error",
      {
        "endOfLine": "auto"
      }
    ],
    "quotemark": [
      true,
      "single",
      "jsx-double"
    ],
    "arrow-parens": false,
    "object-literal-sort-keys": false,
    "jsx-no-lambda": false
  }
}
```

install tslint dependencies (i use this versions)

```
"tslint": "5.20.0",
"tslint-config-prettier": "1.18.0",
"tslint-plugin-prettier": "2.0.1",
"tslint-react": "4.1.0",
```